# Internet Explorer 11 drops cookies

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, privacy

Internet Explorer 11 drops my session cookies when the privacy settings are set to "High".

The setting is under Internet Options -> Privacy and then set it to "High".

It is still possible for me to log in to Facebook etc, so not all cookies are blocked.

Does anyone know how to allow my session cookie under these IE 11 settings? Unfortunately, asking my customers to change the settings is not an option, since the settings has been locked by their system administrator.

The cookie being set is called `laravel_session`, and is a session cookie (no expiration date; ends when the session ends). On the next request, IE doesn't send the session header.
I have set the P3P header.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking the gear in the upper-right corner and doing the following:

*Internet Options > Privacy > Advanced*

From here, ensure the "O*verride automatic cookie handling*" box is ticked and change "*First-party Cookies*" to "*Prompt*"

As a side note, I personally find it easier to deal with cookie rules in Firefox since it allows you to set rules for specific cookies in the settings.